# Can't upload Image CodeIgniter, filetype error

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have write below code :

```
function upld_logo()
     {
        $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';


        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $data['msg']='Sorry! Cant Upload' . $error['error'];
           $data['main_content']='message';
           $this->load->view('template',$data);


        }   
        else
        {
            //$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $names = $this->upload->data();
            $k=$names['file_name'];


            $data['msg']='Your Logo Successfully Uploaded. ';
           $data['main_content']='message';
           $this->load->view('template',$data); 
        }

     }
```

When I upload Image file with name logo.gif it show error message :

**The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.**

Comment: It works in my Local PC but when upload it show above error

Comment: Shouldn't your message be "Sorry! Cant Upload: The filetype...." ?

Comment: Have you checked the web server access and error logs for any PHP or permissions errors?

Comment: check another image, your logo.gif might not be a .gif

Answer (score 4):

Find this code in your system->libraries->Upload.php line 200

```
$this->file_type = preg_replace("/^(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $this->file_type);
```

and replace with this:

```
$this->file_type = preg_replace("/^(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $_FILES[$field]['type']);
```

Comment: This worked for me. Strange that it wasn't an issue on the localhost server but was on the live. Suppose it could be linux related.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I also got the same error.
And if u change the `$[allowed_types] = "*"` (allowed all files) 
you will find that upload is success but your image file don't have a type!

I think there's something wrong with the CI library maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I have spent some time with the same issue. You might find codeigniters default upload library is using a couple of deprecated PHP functions to find the files mime type.... Good luck, I'm still trying to patch it myself .

Comment: After looking into this even further the functions in the Upload class which seem to be unavailable on some Apache/PHP setups are: `finfo_file` and `mime_content_type` (Only one of which appears to be deprecated in later versions of PHP at this time, the other is just missing somehow)